# Let $f$ be a strictly decreasing function. Then $\int_{a}^bf^{-1}=bf^{-1}(b)-af^{-1}(a)+\int_{f^{-1}(b)}^{f^{-1}(a)}f $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to prove the fact that if $f$ is a strictly decreasing function, then:$$\int_{a}^bf^{-1}=bf^{-1}(b)-af^{-1}(a)+\int_{f^{-1}(b)}^{f^{-1}(a)}f $$

I have already proven it for strictly increasing functions. In that case, I made a sketch so I could understand the integral with geometry, and then, using the partitions: $$P=({t_0=a,t_1,...,t_n=b})$$
$$P'=(f^{-1} (t_0)=f^{-1}(a),f^{-1}(t_1),...,f^{-1}(t_n)=f^{-1}(b))$$ I computed $L(f^{-1},P)$+$U(f,P')$ and the rest of the proof was easy to develop.

However, I can't prove it when $f$ is strictly decreasing, neither can I see it geometrically.
Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

If $f$ is strictly decreasing, then $g:=-f$ is strictly increasing, and 
$$
g^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}(-y).
$$

So, by using the result for the strictly increasing functions, you get
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_a^bf^{-1}(x)\,dx&=\int_a^b g^{-1}(-x)\,dx\\
&=-\int_{-a}^{-b}g^{-1}(x)\,dx\\
&=-\left((-b)g^{-1}(-b)-(-a)g^{-1}(-a)+\int_{g^{-1}(-b)}^{g^{-1}(-a)}g(x)\,dx\right)\\
&=-\left(-bf^{-1}(b)-(-a)f^{-1}(a)+\int_{f^{-1}(b)}^{f^{-1}(a)}-f(x)\,dx\right)\\
&=bf^{-1}(b)-af^{-1}(a)+\int_{f^{-1}(b)}^{f^{-1}(a)}f(x)\,dx.
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Thanks, didnt see it that way

Answer (score 4):

By using integration by parts,
$$\int_a^b1\cdot f^{-1}(x)dx=b\cdot f^{-1}(b)-a\cdot f^{-1}(a)-\int_a^b(f^{-1}(x))'xdx$$
In the end substitute $f^{-1}(x)=t$
thus,you get,
$$\int_a^b1\cdot f^{-1}(x)dx=b\cdot f^{-1}(b)-a\cdot f^{-1}(a)-\int_{f^{-1}(a)}^{f^{-1}(b)}f(x)dx$$

Answer (score 4):

The lighter region is the integral on your left-hand side.

[image: picture proof of the claim]

You have $$\int_a^bf^{-1}=+U-V+W$$