# $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ is strictly decreasing continuous function with $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$. Then $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}f^{-1}(y)dy$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ be a strictly decreasing continuous function with $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=0$. Then show that $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}f^{-1}(y)dy$

I was thinking to do it by constructing a function then using Lagrange MVT on it. But I am undone.

Comment: That not true...

Comment: I think yours is a special case of this:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199283/let-f-be-a-strictly-decreasing-function-then-int-abf-1-bf-1b-af?rq=1

Comment: The proof isn't so simple especially if we don't assume that $f$ is differentiable. I'd suggest you check the picture [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions) and try to understand why the formula in the article makes sense.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1115222.

Answer (score 4):

$\int_0^1f(x)dx$ is the area under the curve $y=f(x)$ for $0\le x\le 1$. But $f$ is strictly decreasing, so this is the same as the area to the *left* of the curve. If we reflect this picture about the line $y=x$, the curve traces the function $y=f^{-1}(x)$; and the area is unchanged, but it is now seen to be the region *under* the curve $y=f^{-1}(x)$.

Comment: I think most instructors would not accept this as an answer.  "Area" is *defined* by the integral itself.  Before one learns the integral the concept of area is undefined except for rectangles and triangles, etc.  You are assuming properties of "area" that would need to be proved by properties of the "integral."  It is, however,  a good intuitive explanation of why this should be true.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson: I was not treating it as a homework assignment.

Comment: I would tend to interpret your answer as a good hint of how to "show that" this statement holds.  The other two answers here took your hint and went with it.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson It is an answer from high above. I bet Newton and Leibnitz would have accepted it as an obvious proof. Doubts came later.

Answer (score 1):

Almost a rephrasing of @TonyK 's  answer. As $f$ and $f^{-1}$ decrease
\begin{equation}
\int_{[0, 1]^2}[y \le f(x)] dx dy = \int_{[0, 1]^2}[f^{-1}(y) \ge x] dx dy
\end{equation}
where $[]$ is [Iverson's bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket).

Comment: I think this answer is clearer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another proof base on Fubini's theorem. Assuming $f$ is strictly monotone decreasing and continuous with $f(0)=1$ and $f(1)=1$,
$$A=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2:0\leq x\leq 1,\,0\leq y\leq f(x)\}=\{(x,y)\in[0,1]^2: 0\leq y\leq 1,\,0\leq x\leq f^{-1}(y)\}$$
Hence

$$\begin{align}\int^1_0f(x)\,dx&=\int^1_0\Big(\int^{f(x)}_{0}\,dy\Big)\,dx=\int_{[0,1]\times[0,1]}\mathbb{1}_{A}(x,y)\,dx\,dy\\
&=\int^1_0\Big(\int^{f^{-1}(y)}_0dx\Big)\,dy=\int^1_0f^{-1}(y)\,dy
\end{align}$$

---

Edit: I was typing this when TonyK's solution pop-up. My posting is just to formalized his geometric idea.